# Lord Krishna using the Sudarshan chakra

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, sudarsana

Lord Krishna used the Sudarshan chakra against Shishupal. Are there any other instances in the Life of Lord Krishna i.e. birth till death when he used the Sudarshan chakra?

Comment: many time he used it like against Narakasura, Banasura, Śatadhanwa and Indra etc.. ur actual question was how many times.. do u need a number or my edit is okay?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes Lord Krishna used sudarshana chakra against many other people except sisupala .

https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/78/12/ Srimad Bhagavat puran 10.78.11- 10.78.12 describes slaying of vidhuratha.

https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/77/35/ Srimad bhagavat puran 10.77.9 -10.77.36 describe slaying of salva

https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/57/21/ Srimad Bhagavat puran 10.57.21 shows slaying of satadhanva

https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/59/21/ shows slaying of bhaumasura(naraksura)

https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/59/10/ shows slaying of mura

https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/63/32/ shows arms of banasura being severed

Comment: Hey just saw your answer +1. You’ve gotten a few good incidents. You can also refer to my above answer for more. From the bhagavatam, There are also - saving the Brahmins son, Paundraka and Kashi burning incident,

Comment: @Archit ya. I saw your answer too its great  , I never thought that except from srimad bhagavat puran there will instances in vishnu parva etc.

Comment: Haha no even I used to think that. Much of the actual story is supposed to be contained in Harivamsa/ Mahabharata. What Ramayana is to Shri Rama, Harivamsa and Mahabharata are to Shri Krishna. Current Harivamsa obviously has British Era discrepancies which is why some incidents are only referred to and not described and some extras non-Krishna related find mention. Bhagavatam covers may puranic incidents and is more like a Bhakti Granth, though primary focus is on Krishna.

Comment: @Archit yaa that's true

Answer (score 6):

The first time after his birth, Shri Krishna gets his Chakra during the time when Jarasandha lays siege to Mathura, thereafter its used in almost every leela of his (listed the 13 documented ones), before returning to Vaikuntha.

1. **Getting the chakra - The battle with Jarasandha**:

> The plough named saMvartaka, the club named saunandaM, the great bow shAr~NgaM and the mace (gada), kaumodaki. The conch, **discus** and the sword , splendorous as the sun with thousand rays, capable of killing the enemies and kheTakaM, the quiver with everlasting supply of arrows. All these four splendorous weapons of viShNu arrived for (assisting) the yAdava-s in the great battle. *keshava was pleased to pick up the discus named sudarshanaM*, fascinating to be seen in the worlds, splendorous as the sun. 
>  *Harivamsa Vishnu Parva, 43.9, 9a, 13*

2. **The Retrieval of the Syamantaka Mani**:

> As Śatadhanvā fled on foot, the Supreme Lord, also going on foot, *cut off his head with His sharp-edged disc*. The Lord then searched Śatadhanvā’s upper and lower garments for the Syamantaka jewel. 
>  *ŚB 10.57.21*

3. **The Yajna at Kailasa** for a son. Here the Sudarshana helped in getting necessary ingredients:

> The king of Chakras collects flowers for Hari. 
> *Harivamsa Bhavishya Parva 84.21*

4. **Elimination of Vajranabha** - here he gives the discus to his son.

> O the one of bharata race! (janamejaya! vaishampAyana continued) *the chakra, the destroyer of thousands*, the slayer of the races of demons, went to pradyumna's hand, as desired by Krishna. *Harivamsa, Vishnu Parva, 97.16*

5. **The Slaying of Narakasura:**

> The slayer of madhu (kR^iShNa) fought naraka for some time. With his *sparkling discus*, he cut the terrible naraka in two.
>  *Harivamsa Vishnu Parva 63.120*

6. **The Shatpura demon Nikumbha**:

> *The discus sudarshana released from the hand of Narayana*, sparkling like the sun cut off the head of nikumbha, decorated with the best earrings. 
>  *Harivamsa Vishnu Parva 85.62*

7. **Paundraka ‘Vasudeva’ episode**:

> Having split his body, *the Chakra returned quickly* to the hand of Krishna, Lord of all.
>  *Harivamsa Bhavishya Parva 101.24*

8. **Burning of the city of Kashi**:

> After burning down the entire city of Vārāṇasī, *Lord Viṣṇu’s Sudarśana cakra returned to the side of Śrī Kṛṣṇa*, whose actions are effortless. 
>  *ŚB 10.66.42*

9. **The deliverance of Shishupala** at Yudhishthira’s Rajasuya Yajna:

> Having said this, the chief of the Yadus, that slayer of all foes, in anger, instantly *cut off the head of the ruler of Chedi by means of his discus.* 
>  *Mahabharata Sabha Parva [Chapter 44](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m02/m02044.htm)*

10. **The Slaying of Shalva**:

> The discus then cleft Salwa in twain who in that fierce conflict was at the point of hurling a heavy mace. And with its energy it set the foe ablaze *Mahabharata Vana Parva [Chapter 22](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03022.htm)*

11. **The Slaying of Viduratha**:

> O best of kings, as Vidūratha fell upon Him, Lord Kṛṣṇa used His razor-edged Sudarśana disc to remove his head, complete with its helmet and earrings. 
>  *ŚB 10.78.12*

12. **The Severing of Banasura’s hands**

> The one who destroys the splendor of demons in the battle field with his own splendor, the one who holds shrI (kR^iShNa), the one having high splendor, cut off bANa's arms with the chakra. 
>  *Harivamsa Vishnu Parva 126.127*

13. **Saving the Brahmin’s son**:

> Then govinda (kR^iShNa) broke the darkness with his chakra and showed a best way in the sky for the chariot to move. 
>  *Harivamsa Vishnu Parva 113.23*

14. **The return of the Sudarshana to Vaikuntha** along with Shri Krishna. This was the last time the Chakra made an appearance before going back:

> Encircling His body were flower garlands and His personal weapons in their embodied forms. 
>  *ŚB 11.30.32*

There are many more incidents related to Shri Krishna’s life that have only been referred to in the Mahabharata and Harivamsa, like the taming of kings of various countries and getting free from the binds of some asuras. However in the current versions of scriptures these are not documented. So besides the above in reality he may have possibly used to Chakra multiple times in those incidents.

---

<sup>In the first incident of the Chakra coming down, verse 9a has been taken from the The Harivamsa, critically edited by P.L.Vaidya, Volume II, page 112, Bhandarkar Oriental Research Institute, Poona, 1971. Also please note, that the chapter in Harivamsa refers to the weapons in the Gomanta incident, but they actually appear the first time Jarasandha lays siege. This can be verified from the relevant chapter in Harivamsa as well as the Srimad Bhagavatham. In the Gomanta incident there is no fight.</sup>

Comment: not in parijat episode against Indra?

Comment: @YDS no, In Parijata episode they’re fighting only with bow and arrows. Bhagavatham doesn’t give much description either. But I missed the one where he is performing a yajna

Comment: "When all the other weapons had been cut to pieces, Indra stood armed with his thunderbolt, and Krishńa with the discus Sudarśana. " ~https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp147.htm actually in list like answers, list is never complete..thats why the Q should be focused..only few instances in answer is okay for such Qs..

Comment: @YDS okay yes I agree. This is from Vishnu Purana. Sorry I was referring only to Harivamsa and Bhagavatam where both have only bhagavan using arrows.